# Capture filename parts: Why doesn't this regexp work?

Tags: regex

I'm faily new to regexp and I miss something from capturing groups.

Let's suppose I have a filepath like that

```
test.orange.john.edn
```

I want to capture two groups:

```
test.orange.john (which is the body)
edn (which is the extension)
```

I used this (and variants of it, taking the $ outside, etc.)

```
^([a-z]*.)*.([a-z]*$)
```

But it captures xm only

What did I miss? I do not understand why l is not captured and the body too...
I found answers on the web to capture the extension but I do not understand the problem there.

Thanks

Comment: Escape the dot to match a literal dot. [`^(.*)\.([a-z]*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/pO8lS7/1) or even [`^(.*)\.(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/pO8lS7/2) will do.

Comment: Oh thanks I did not know that the dot was used in the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^([a-z]*.)*.([a-z]*$)` regex is very inefficient as there are lots of unnecessary backtracking steps here.

The start of string is matched, and then `[a-z]*.` is matched 0+ times. That means, the engine matches as many `[a-z]` as possible (i.e. it matches `test` up to the first dot), and then `.` matches the dot (but only because `.` matches any character!). So, this `([a-z]*.)*` matches `test.orange.john.edn` *only* capturing `edn` since repeating capturing groups only keep the last captured value.

You already have `edn` in Group 1 [at this step](https://regex101.com/r/uX5qJ1/1). Now, `.([a-z]*$)` should allocate a substring for the `.` (any character) pattern. Backtracking goes back and finds `n` - now, [Group 1 only contains `ed`](https://regex101.com/r/uX5qJ1/2).

For your task, you should escape the last `.` to match a *literal dot* and perhaps, the best expression is

```
^(.*)\.(.*)$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pO8lS7/2)

It will match all the string up to the end with the first `(.*)`, and then will backtrack to find the last `.` symbol (so, Group 1 will have all text from the beginning till the last `.`), and then capturing the rest of the string into Group 2.

If a dot does not have to be present (i.e. if a file name has no extension), add an optional group:

```
^(.*)(?:\.(.*))?$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/pO8lS7/4)

Comment: Oh ok i understand now the use of the dot plus you are right, any character can be matched and not only a-z !

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
^([a-z.]+)\.([a-z]+)$
```

[online example](https://regex101.com/r/pB5fO4/1)

Comment: Thanks too, I forgot the meaning of [], I tought it could only contain a range ! I just replaced the first + because certain files have no names ^([a-z.]*)\.([a-z]+)$